# Can interface implementation member be of a derived class of interface member

Tags: c#

In short, suppose there is an interface

```
interface IListInterface
{
    IList<int> List { get; }
}
```

I have a class that has a member of ObservableItemCollection which implements the IList somewhere in it's parents:

```
class Model 
{
    ObservableItemCollection<int> List { get; }
}
```

Is there a way to make Model be considered IListInterface without adding explicit implementation? (e.g. following with no errors?)

```
class Model : IListInterface 
{
    ObservableItemCollection<int> List { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has actually [been proposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns#interface-method-property-and-indexer-override) together with the covariant return types feature in C# 9. However, it seems to have not been implemented, possibly because supporting implicit interface implementations would be a source-breaking change (See the end of [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns#implicit-interface-implementations)).

Since covariant return *is* implemented for class methods, you can add a dummy abstract base class for `Model` and override the getter in that class:

```
abstract class ModelBase: IListInterface {
    public abstract IList<int> List { get; }
}

class Model : ModelBase
{
    public override ObservableItemCollection<int> List { get; }
}
```

Alternatively, add a covariant generic parameter to your interface:

```
interface IListInterface<out TList> where TList: IList<int>
{
    TList List { get; }
}

class Model : IListInterface<ObservableItemCollection<int>>
{
    public ObservableItemCollection<int> List { get; }
}
```

And you'd use `IListInterface<IList<int>>` everywhere, pretending the generic type doesn't exist :) Since `TList` is covariant, it is possible to implicitly convert a `Model` to `IListInterface<IList<int>>`.

You can even add a global using alias for this, if you really want:

```
global using DefinitelyNotGenericIListInterface = 
    YourNamespace.IListInterface<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>;
```